# creating python code on IDLE then using it in macOS terminal

Tags: python, macos, file, terminal, python-idle

I'm wondering how I can utilize my code on IDLE to work within the macOS Terminal.
For example, I created a function such as:
`def multiplication_by_2(x): return 2 * x`

and saved the .py file in a desktop folder.

I want to use terminal to test out various cases such as `multipication_by_2(100)` etc, however I am unsure about which commands to enter in terminal to achieve this.

Any direction toward this would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: generally, the command is `python`...

Comment: This is fundamental material that you should be able to learn from following basically any tutorial, and which you should approach that way. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: For example, you could try the [tutorial built into the official documentation on docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). The link will specifically take you to the relevant section, on *modules*. (Another advantage of following tutorials from the start, even if you think you know most of what you want to know, is that you end up *learning what things are called*.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to send arguments to your program through the command line, python's `sys` library has a list named `argv` that holds arguments passed from the command line. Add this to your python file:

```
from sys import argv
for argument in argv:
    print(multipication_by_2(int(argument))) # All arguments are strings by default
```

Then in the command line, do `python file_name.py 20 50 1` and any other number you might want to try, and the program will print its double.

Note: If your command line says `python` doesn't exist, try `python3`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't guess at what OP wants. The way the site works, the burden is on OP to clarify the question, and that question should not be answered until it is clear. Additionally, someone who is having *this* much difficulty is better served by following a tutorial than by trying to ask questions on Stack Overflow - hence the comments at the top and votes to close the question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel and p.s.,  It is up to the viewer to determine whether or not they'll be able to help me and I recognize not everyone will have the time to do so. I will continue asking questions when I am stuck, despite your attempt at policing my learning process. Many tutorials I've seen haven't covered this terminal dilemma I am having.

Comment: I gave you a link that explicitly gives you the relevant information, right at the top of the page. Stack Overflow is not for all the kinds of questions you might expect it to be for. In fact, *most* people who come to Stack Overflow seem to be expecting it to be a very different website from what it is actually intended to be. Other things you can try doing include web searches specific to the problem you are having, web searches for tutorials generally, and *using actual forum websites* such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: I do not "have a problem"; there is a specific way this website is supposed to work and I am explaining how it works so that people can participate in the intended manner.

Comment: lwashington27, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of the code:

```
number = int(str(input("Enter the number you would like to multiply by 2: ")))
multiplication_by_2(number)
```

This way, you get user input. Then, in the terminal:

```
$ python3 <filename>.py
```

Which should produce the output:

```
Enter the number you would like to multiply: <your input, ex. 100>
200
```

Hope that solved it!

Comment: You would have to convert the input from a string to an integer to work. Otherwise, the program will print the number twice.

Comment: Would you mind selecting the answer as answering? That would help others find it easier. Just click the checkmark below the votes.